# How to round values created in dataframe column using lambda?

Tags: python, data-science, computer-science

I've used the following code in order to find the sum of a column's values and store it:

```
FavCountSum=Merge3['Favorite_Count'].sum()
```

and then I've used the following code in order to divide each number in the original column by the stored sum in order to create a new column with the respective percentages and I'd like to know how to round the percentages two decimal places.

```
Merge3.assign(Favorite_Color_Percent=lambda x: x.Favorite_Count/FavCountSum)
```

Answer (score 1):

try it:

```
Merge3.assign(Favorite_Color_Percent=lambda x: round(x.Favorite_Count/FavCountSum, 2))
```

Comment: It returns an error stating, "cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>"

Comment: oh sorry, you maybe remove float, I edited above